# Redirect URL to new URL

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2, routes, traffic

How do I redirect all traffic from test/(.*) to http://newdomain.com/test/$1? I tried this, but that didn't work: `RewriteRule ^test/(.*) http://domain.com/test/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Probably a typo but did you mean to redirect to domain.com or newdomain.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to add a slash to the beginning of the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*) http://domain.com/test/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the line `RewriteEngine On` before your rewrite rule.